# hiding div element in code behind

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have built a slideshow. Each of the slides has a div placed over the top of it. The div contains some text. What I want to do is if the `h2` and `p` element have no text then hide the div that contains them. I have attempted to hide the div from the repeaters DataBound event but it is still showing the div over the slide.

Here's what I have so far:

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSlides" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnItemDataBound="rptSlides_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="slideDiv" class="slide">
            <img runat="server" src='<%# Eval("slideImgPath")%>' />
            <div id="slideTextdiv" runat="server" class="slideText">
                <h2 id="titlePlaceHolder" runat="server" class="slideTitle text-center text-capitalize h2 ">
                    <%# Eval("slideTitle") %>
                </h2>
                <p id="textPlaceHolder" runat="server" class="slideDes">
                    <%# Eval("slideDesc") %>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void rptSlides_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptSlides.Items)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl titleText = (HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("titlePlaceHolder");
        HtmlGenericControl slidetextDesc = (HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("textPlaceHolder");
        HtmlGenericControl slideDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("slideTextdiv");

        if (titleText.InnerText == "" && slidetextDesc.InnerText == "")
        {
            slideDiv.Style.Add("Display", "none");                
        }
    }
}
```

**Further info**

I have also tried the following:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptSlides.Items)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl slideDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControlRecursive(item, "slideTextdiv");
        HtmlGenericControl titleText = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControlRecursive(item, "titlePlaceHolder");
        HtmlGenericControl slidetextDesc = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControlRecursive(item, "textPlaceHolder");


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(titleText.InnerText) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slidetextDesc.InnerText))
        {
            slideDiv.Attributes["class"] = "emptySlideText";
        }
    }
```

I created a class in the css called emptySlideText, like so:

```
.emptySlideText {
display:none; }
```

Unfortunatley this has had no effect.

I have also tried changing the line

slideDiv.Style.Add("Display", "none");

to

slideDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

But again it made no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need a `foreach` loop inside your `rptSlides_ItemDataBound` event as `ItemDataBound` event of a repeater control iterates for each item. Next `Div` is not a `HtmlGenericControl` control rather it is `HtmlControl` control. Once you have this you can hide the div using `Visible` property like this:-

```
protected void rptSlides_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
   {
       HtmlControl slideTextdiv = (HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("slideTextdiv");
       HtmlGenericControl titlePlaceHolder = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("titlePlaceHolder");
       HtmlGenericControl textPlaceHolder = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("textPlaceHolder");

       if (titlePlaceHolder != null)
               titlePlaceHolder.InnerText = Regex.Replace(titlePlaceHolder.InnerText, @"\r\n?|\n", "").Trim();

       if (textPlaceHolder != null)
               textPlaceHolder.InnerText = Regex.Replace(textPlaceHolder.InnerText, @"\r\n?|\n", "").Trim();

       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(titlePlaceHolder.InnerText) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(textPlaceHolder.InnerText))
       {
           slideTextdiv.Visible = false;
       }
   }
}
```

Please include `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to import `Regex` class.

Comment: @M_Griffiths - Ok can you tell me what values you are passing in `slideTitle` & `slideDesc`? I have tested this code by passing `""`,`"    "` both and it's working fine for me.

Comment: it pulls the text from the database but not every slide has text to display as the db allows null in those columns. I'm not sure how the databinding works with null value

Comment: @M_Griffiths - Hey check my update, once you said `nulls`, I updated my code and was able to replicate the issue. It's happening cz of line breaks, now it's fixed and should work for you.

Comment: Thank you soo much, you have saved me :)